# Problemas com Fragments: Activity has been destroyed

Tags: android-fragment

Meu `navigation drawer` está correto, mas quando você clica num item do drawer, e ele vai dar um replace nos fragments, a aplicação pára, e no logcat aparece mensagem de erro dizendo que

> Activity has been destroyed

Código:

```
class DrawerItemClickListener extends FragmentActivity implements         ListView.OnItemClickListener {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    selectItem(position);
}

private void selectItem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null; 

    switch(position)
    {
    case 0:
        fragment = new DadosCadastraisDilmaFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new DadosCadastraisAecioFragment();
        break;
    ...
            default:
            break;
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
}
}

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

private String [] listaCandidatos;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout; 
private ListView drawerList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // inicializar a lista do drawer
    listaCandidatos = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lista_candidatos);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item,R.id.drawerListItemTextView, listaCandidatos));
    // Set the list's click listener 
    drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que o  `DrawerItemClickListener` herda de `FragmentActivity`. E está fazendo reposições de `Fragment` em uma `Activity` (`DrawerItemClickListener`) usando o `FragmentManager`, que não foi criada pelo `ActivityManager` (parte do framework Android).

A mensagem:

> Activity has been destroyed

É causada porque essa `Activity` não foi iniciada. Então para ele está destruída.

Remova essa herança e faça com que o `DrawerItemClickListener` seja declarado não estático dentro da `MainActivity`.

Mais ou menos assim:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    // Restante do codigo

    public class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        // Restante do seu código

    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Funcionou!